# How to test my app on ios 7 using Xcode 6 simulator

Tags: ios7, xcode6, ios-simulator

I'm trying to test my app with ios7 using Xcode 6's simulator but I can't find the option to change it. Currently it only loads ios8 while my deployment target is set to 7.

Also according to this message from Apple:

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Does this mean that new apps cannot run on ios7 anymore?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: All iPhone Simulator version don't support iOS7 (iPhone 6/6+ for example). Did you download the iOS7 Simulator ? (In Preferences)?

Comment: Hi yes I did, I'm not sure where to change the option in the simulator to load ios7 though.

Comment: Did you download at least the iOS7 simulator?

Comment: My bad guys, it said there ios7 simulator in my preferences I thought it was downloaded. Turned out I had to click the arrow to download it.  Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 2):

First, Change Deployment Target to 7.You can change Deployment target from target under Deployment Info.
Go to Xcode Preferences, Select Downloads tab and download iOS7 Simulator.
Now go to Xcode, you can find iOS7 Simulator on target device list, if not than quit and restart Xcode.
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The deployment target is the minimum version of iOS that your application will be expected to run on.  It effects how your app is *BUILT* and not where you run it.  You need to choose an iOS 7 device from the run destinations menu and then do a Build&Run to build, install, and run the app on the iOS 7 device.

If you don't have an iOS 7 simulator device in the run destinations menu, go download the iOS 7 runtime from Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

Comment: No option of Downloads, there is a option of Components, but it doesn't list iOS 7 simulator. Refer this image:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79649352/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-19%20at%2012.19.01%20PM.png

Comment: Yes, the tab was renamed to Components (I think in Xcode 7).  The iOS 7 Simulator Runtime is not supported on El Capitan or Sierra.  You can only download the iOS 7.1 Simulator Runtime if you are still on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, go to xcode(7) preferences>select Components here you can download Simulater and Documents also.

Comment: Only > iOS 8 available here